# How to get rid of box around linked image

Tags: html, css, image, anchor

I know I've solved this problem before, but I can't remember or find the solution, so here I am...

In Firefox 3.5 this code causes an undesirable blue border around the image. How do I get rid of this blue border?

```
<a style="text-decoration: none;" href="index.html">
    <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/stpatricksday10-hp.gif" />
</a>
```

http://jsbin.com/umuzo3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a img { border: none; }
```

Should do the trick (works in IE6).

Comment: It certainly works here. Are you sure you're _saving_ the template after you make an edit?

Comment: Ah, silly I was applying to the `a` and not the `img` works now see http://jsbin.com/umuzo3/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting image border to 0 px.