# how to get rid of firefox image border

Tags: html, css, image, firefox

I've recently added an image to my website, where the image is wrapped in an anchor tag, like this: .

The problem is, that this image has a border, but only in firefox; no border is showing in chrome. I want the border to go away. I have set in the css for both the a and img tags, the following:

```
text-decoration:none;
border-style:none;
border:none;
outline:none;
box-shadow: 0;
-moz-box-shadow:0;
background:none;
color:white;
```

The image is a small gray icon on a white background, and I have double checked it in gimp and there is definitely no border around the image. So, what have I missed? Where is it coming from? Why does it only appear in firefox? And how do I make it go away?

Firefox version is 17.0.1

Comment: Possible duplicates: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328077/how-to-get-rid-of-border-around-and-image-used-as-a-link-in-firefox?rq=1) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466590/how-to-get-rid-of-box-around-linked-image?rq=1)

Comment: @thordarson Not a dupe - the answers to those questions were border:none and outline:none, which I already have; besides, my border is gray, not pink or blue.

Comment: Can you repeat the problem on a fiddle?

Comment: @PavloMykhalov No - I put my code in a fiddle, and the image appeared with no border there. There's something about my site that's causing it; I just can't find what.

Comment: Show us more code, we can't read your mind.

Comment: Try uncheck 'normalize.css' on the left of your fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unbelievably, I found the answer - turns out that I had zoomed in, and I didn't notice because it was only by one. Wasn't until I went and pasted the entire contents of my page in jsfiddle that I noticed the sizes were marginally different.

Apparently, when firefox zooms in it adds borders to images. Can't imagine why, but once I zoomed out the borders went away. Problem solved, I guess. Just wish I'd found this sooner - it's been bugging me for days!

Comment: Glad you solved it. By all means, accept your answer as the solution so people know this is solved.

Comment: @thordarson Will do, as soon as it lets me - although I'm upvoting yours for the jsfiddle suggestion, which led to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

**So, what have I missed?**

The 90s and 00s.

**Where is it coming from?**

It's coming from the browser's default stylesheet.

**Why does it only appear in firefox?**

Browsers seem to make up their own rules on whether they display a border around linked images or not.

**And how do I make it go away?**

```
a img {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Except that I already have that. You can see in the question, I've already included this in the css for both a and img tags.

Comment: You need to be more specific with your rules. `a img` overrides `img` as a rule as it's more specific.

Comment: In the original CSS you don't show us what those are attributed to.

Comment: My css is "a, a img {" to get them both. Chrome and firefox/firebug both report that nothing is being overridden, and it is displaying correctly in chrome